# How do you load a scene unto a stage from another class?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to separate certain sections of a program so that everything is organized. I want my Main.java to contain the initial settings that need to load. Then it starts the app(loads the stage) from MainStage.java, which in turn loads a scene from another class (SceneOne.java, SceneTwo.Java, etc.).
SceneOne.java and the rest contains all the objects (textbox, button, labels, etc.) that are to be included in the scene. There might be an "unnecessary" step by having a MainStage.java, but I'm not sure about that. Still, my goal right now is to figure out how to load a scene from SceneOne.java. 
This is what I have so far, which I mostly got from some tutorial site.

Main.java

```
package ppmp.main;
import ppmp.ui.MainStage;
import javafx.application.*;

public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Application Starting");
        Application.launch(MainStage.class);
    }
}
```

MainStage.java

```
package ppmp.ui;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class MainStage extends Application {
    Button btnscene1, btnscene2;
    Label lblscene1, lblscene2;
    FlowPane pane1, pane2;
    Scene scene1, scene2;
    Stage thestage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        thestage=primaryStage;
        //can now use the stage in other methods

        //make things to put on panes
        btnscene1=new Button("Click to go to Other Scene");
        btnscene2=new Button("Click to go back to First Scene");
        btnscene1.setOnAction(e-> ButtonClicked(e));
        btnscene2.setOnAction(e-> ButtonClicked(e));
        lblscene1=new Label("Scene 1");
        lblscene2=new Label("Scene 2");

        //make 2 Panes
        pane1=new FlowPane();
        pane2=new FlowPane();
        pane1.setVgap(10);
        pane2.setVgap(10);
        //set background color of each Pane
        pane1.setStyle("-fx-background-color: tan;-fx-padding: 10px;");
        pane2.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;-fx-padding: 10px;");

        //add everything to panes
        pane1.getChildren().addAll(lblscene1, btnscene1);
        pane2.getChildren().addAll(lblscene2, btnscene2);

        //make 2 scenes from 2 panes
        scene1 = new Scene(pane1, 200, 100);
        scene2 = new Scene(pane2, 200, 100);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void ButtonClicked(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getSource()==btnscene1)
            thestage.setScene(scene2);
        else
            thestage.setScene(scene1);
    }
}
```

SceneOne.java

```
package ppmp.ui;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.event.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class SceneOne extends Scene {

    public static class MyStackPane extends StackPane{
        public MyStackPane() {
            getChildren().add(new Label("Hello World"));
        }
    }
}
```

A very specific question would be, what should I replace scene1 with to load SceneOne.java in primaryStage.setScene(scene1);?

Edit: I forgot to mention, I know most of the codes for a scene are in the MainStage.java. I'm trying to figure out how to transfer all of those into SceneOne.java.

Comment: Your `SceneOne` class won't compile like that, will it?

Comment: No it wouldn't. I tried changing it to public class SceneOne extends Pane, instead of public class SceneOne extends Scene based on some other answer I found that was related to this issue. I just put it there so people would have a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve.